# inline assembler increment 64bit counter

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit, inline-assembly

I'd like to increment the 64bit(long type in C++) counter in inline assembly atomically. I know how to do that on 32bit value(int):

```
asm volatile("lock; incl %0" : "=m" (val) : "m"(val));
```

But I have no idea how to perform that on long value.

Comment: And for what CPU? Some have [cmpxchg8b](http://www.niallryan.com/node/137), but not all.

Comment: Ok, know I see that there is only some problem related to overflow, cause I've got strange values only when I increment value -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*moved self answer from the question to an answer*

It was quite easy, but I haven't been familiar with x86-64.

```
asm volatile("lock; incq %0" : "=m" (val) : "m"(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
asm volatile("lock; incq %0" : "+m" (val));
```

Specifying separate operands without constraints that force input into the same location as the output could result in code such as:

```
val = something;
asm volatile("lock; incq %0" : "=m" (val) : "m"(val));
```

being optimised wrongly. You may also need a memory clobber to prevent accesses to other variables being moved past the asm.